# Searching for records with missing property in an array of the JSON field (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table that contains all the products. The product properties are stored in a JSON field called properties. Inside the JSON object I have a property for storing the product image paths. The structure looks like this:

```
{..., "images": [{"original": "path/to/original", "icon": "path/to/icon", "small": "path/to/small"}, {"original": "path/to/original"}], ...}
```

As you can see the second image doesn't have any sizes other than the original meaning my app should create the different sizes of this image. The problem is I cannot filter for records like this which doesn't have "small" or "icon" (or any arbitrary size) properties in one of the array in elements within the images.
I tried the following WHERE condition:

```
... WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(properties, 'one', '$.images') AND JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(properties, 'all', '$.images[*].icon', '$.images[*].small') = 0;
```

Unfortunately this won't work. In my understanding the second JSON_CONTAINS_PATH should search for records which misses the icon or small property within any of the elements of the images array. Clearly that's not the case.

Which JSON function to use? (if JSON_CONTAINS_PATH is not the right one for this purpose) What to change on the query? (if it is)

Comment: What result do you expect from the query?. Some ideas that can be useful, [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a821e8bc2ec25a33b2b8f04ae66bdc05). Evaluate the possible performance problems.

Comment: Try [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/giDPRMjwZ4swDNeFKme4UD/0).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is going on here but I am not able to recreate you problem.

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl/stack] SQL> select * from q1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(pro
erties, 'one', '$.images') and JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(properties,'all','$.images[*]
icon','$.images[*].small');
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | properties
                                                                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"name": "test", "images": [{"icon": "path/to/icon", "small": "path/to/s
all", "original": "path/to/original"}, {"original": "path/to/original"}]} |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.0013 sec)
```

and the json_contains_path(properties,'all','$.images[*].icon') by itself and json_contains_path(properties,'all','$.images.small') by itself work.

So i know the records that match are being found. To get a 'no match' I need a record that does not match. I am going to NARROW it down so that the new record does not have a 'small' object in the images array.

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl/stack] SQL> insert into q1 (id,properties) values(2,'{"nam
e" : "test2", "images": [{"icon": "path/2/icon", "medium": "path2/icon"}]}');
```

Rerun your query:

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl/stack] SQL> select * from q1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(prop
erties, 'one', '$.images') and JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(properties,'all','$.images[*].
icon','$.images[*].small') = 0;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
------+
| id | properties
      |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
------+
|  2 | {"name": "test2", "images": [{"icon": "path/2/icon", "medium": "path2/ico
n"}]} |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
------+
1 row in set (0.0020 sec)
```

I get similar results testing for 'icon'.  So I am not sure what is not working for you.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://justpaste.it/7bv8q
I expect that the result would be the record with the id of 5 in this case.

Comment: Yes, the '= 0' gets the records that do not match the requirement.

Comment: You're right, but the record with the id of 5 should be in the result set cause the second image does not have icon and small size.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by using two different queries:

First I try to figure out the maximum number of images uploaded for a product:

```
select max(json_length(properties, '$.images')) as max_nr_images from products where json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[0]') group by json_length(properties, '$.images');
```

And then I form the where conditions based on this number:

```
select * from products where json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[0]') and (json_contains_path(properties, 'all', '$.images[0].icon', '$.images[0].small') = 0 or if(json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[1]'), json_contains_path(properties, 'all', '$.images[1].icon', '$.images[1].small'), 1) = 0 or if(json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[2]'), json_contains_path(properties, 'all', '$.images[2].icon', '$.images[2].small'), 1) = 0 or if(json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[3]'), json_contains_path(properties, 'all', '$.images[3].icon', '$.images[3].small'), 1) = 0 or if(json_contains_path(properties, 'one', '$.images[4]'), json_contains_path(properties, 'all', '$.images[4].icon', '$.images[4].small'), 1) = 0);
```

(This one is for four images.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using MySQL 8.0 syntax is to use the [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) function. This allows for generating a table from a JSON Array.

See this [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6m4qHDnth5sGdptyTB9P1r/1) for an example using your schema.

Embedding the code here in case the DB Fiddle link doesn't work in the future:

```
SELECT
  `id`, json_t.*
FROM
  `test` t
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    t.properties, 
    '$.images[*]' COLUMNS(
      icon varchar(100) PATH '$.icon',
      small varchar(200) PATH '$.small',
      original varchar(200) PATH '$.original'
    )
  ) as json_t
WHERE
    json_t.small is not null 
    or json_t.original is not null;
```