# MYSQL how to query based on JSON object

Tags: mysql

Hey Stack overflow so I have a JSON object in my rows named translations that looks like such

```
{
    "en": {
        "name": "pants",
        "description": "some description for en"
    },
    "es": {
        "description": "some description for en"
    }
}
```

I need a mysql query where for each element in my table I want to query results where the 'name' property is missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234887/searching-for-records-with-missing-property-in-an-array-of-the-json-field-mysql

Comment: Can you show me an example query I can use?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid could you correct that?

Comment: Is that JSON correct? Its stored in my database that way

Comment: You can try to paste your JSON of question to https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/y22d5d7a7

Comment: Regardless of formatting my json object. How would I construct a query where the nested field name if it does not exist return me those translations from the database

Comment: No, JSON format is important because that might relate to your parse `JSON` path

Comment: Parse your JSON with JSON_TABLE() function then search for incomplete values with according WHERE condition.

Comment: Akina, can you give me an example. @D-Shih I fixed the json formatting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing this in JSON format instead of normal rows and columns?

Comment: It was a requirement that fell upon me while trying to complete the task I was assigned

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: it returns '8.0.28'

Comment: I think your requirements are making this task harder than it should be. I wrote an answer that shows a technique to work around this, using JSON_TABLE() as Akina suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519284/how-to-select-keys-of-objects-in-a-json-array-using-mysql/71519687#71519687

Comment: Can you show a viable answer using JSON table.